# Run Powershell Script on Multiple Remote Computers

Tags: powershell

Good day.

I apologize if this seems like a repetitive question but I the researches I have done have gotten me more confused. I'm trying to run the following Powershell script to delete a folder on some computers:

```
$users = get-childitem c:\users

foreach ($user in $users)
{
$folder = "C:\Users\" + $user + "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive"
Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
}
```

The script seems to work. How can I use this script on a list of remote computers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the Invoke-Command cmdlet with the ComputerName parameter. Example:

```
Invoke-Command { $env:ComputerName } -ComputerName SOMEMACHINE
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [dugas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63345347/11025476), you can use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7) to perform remote script execution using the `-ScriptBlock` and `-ComputerName` parameters.

```
# Create script block using surrounding {}
$sb = {
$users = Get-Childitem C:\Users -Directory -Name

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $folder = "C:\Users\" + $user + "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive"
    Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
}
}
# Create array of computer names since -ComputerName accepts an array
$computers = 'computer1','computer2','computer3'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $sb
```

There are numerous ways to traverse the remote directories. Using `Get-ChildItem` with `-Directory` and `-Name` parameters will return just the folder names under `C:\Users`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having headache with offline computers, inaccwessible computers, etc, if you are using Active Directory domain, ask SysAdmin to create a Run-Once Scheduled Task using Group Policy Preferences.